# Symfony2 User roles vanish between Listener and UserProvider

Tags: security, symfony, symfony-2.1

I'm having trouble (again) with the security component of Symfony2.

First thing first, there are severals objects involved in the process of authentication :

1. SecurityFactoryInterface
2. AbstractAuthenticationListener
3. AuthenticationProviderInterface
4. Custom Token (inherits from AbstractToken)
5. UserProviderInterface

## Flow

If I understand well, the aim of the Security factory is to configure the custom authentication.

The Listener is the conductor of the authentication. Throught its `attemptAuthentication` method it captures the form submission (containing user's credentials) and tries to authenticate the user. Inside this method, the Listener will create an `AbstractToken` and then pass the token to the `authenticate` method of the `AuthenticationProvider`.

After that, the `AuthenticationProvider` calls the `UserProvider` to retrieve the users data from a webservice or database etc...

Once the `UserProvider` did its magic, it returns an User object to the `AuthenticationProvider`.

The AuthenticationProvider then creates an new Token filled with the user retrieved by the `UserProvider` and then retunrs it to the `Listener`.

After getting the new Token, the `Listener` does some unknown magic (I think it sets the token into the security context but I'm not sure).

## Problem

At each steps I did a var_dump of my User object. The roles were set in every steps except in the "final steps": in the `Listener`.

When the `Listener` retrieve the authenticated token from the `UserProvider`, **user's roles are empty**. I can't figure out why...

### SecurityFactory

```
class CompanyFactory implements SecurityFactoryInterface
{
    public function create(ContainerBuilder $container, $id, $config, $userProvider, $defaultEntryPoint)
    {
        $providerId = 'security.authentication.provider.company.'.$id;
        $container
            ->setDefinition($providerId, new DefinitionDecorator('company.security.authentication.provider'))
            ->replaceArgument(0, new Reference($userProvider));

        $listenerId = 'security.authentication.listener.company.'.$id;
        $listener = $container->setDefinition($listenerId, new DefinitionDecorator('company.security.authentication.listener'));

        return array($providerId, $listenerId, $defaultEntryPoint);
    }

    public function getPosition()
    {
        return 'pre_auth';
    }

    public function getKey()
    {
        return 'company';
    }

    public function addConfiguration(NodeDefinition $node)
    {
    }
}
```

### Listener

```
class CompanyListener extends AbstractAuthenticationListener
{
    // Custructor stuff removed

    protected function requiresAuthentication(Request $request)
    {
        if ($this->options['post_only'] && !$request->isMethod('post'))
        {
            return false;
        }

        return parent::requiresAuthentication($request);
    }

    protected function attemptAuthentication(Request $request)
    {
        $username = trim($request->get($this->options['username_parameter'], null, true));
        $password = $request->get($this->options['password_parameter'], null, true);
        $ip       = $request->getClientIp();

        $request->getSession()->set(SecurityContextInterface::LAST_USERNAME, $username);

        $authToken = $this->authenticationManager->authenticate(new CompanyUserToken($username, $password, $ip));

        return $authToken;
    }
}
```

### AuthenticationProvider

```
class CompanyProvider implements AuthenticationProviderInterface
{
    private $userProvider;

    public function __construct(UserProviderInterface $userProvider)
    {
        $this->userProvider = $userProvider;
    }

    public function authenticate(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        $user = $this->userProvider->loadUserByUsernamePassword($token->user, $token->getPassword(), $token->getIp());

        $authenticatedToken = new CompanyUserToken($user->getUsername(), $user->getPassword(), $user->getIp(), $user->getRoles());
        $authenticatedToken->setUser($user);

        return $authenticatedToken;
    }

    public function supports(TokenInterface $token)
    {
        return $token instanceof CompanyUserToken;
    }
}
```

### Custom Token

```
class CompanyUserToken extends AbstractToken
{
    private $password;
    private $ip;

    public function __construct($username, $password, $ip, array $roles = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($roles);

        $this->password = $password;
        $this->user = $username;
        $this->ip = $ip;

        // If the user has roles, consider it authenticated
        $this->setAuthenticated(count($roles) > 0);
    }

    public function getCredentials()
    {
        return '';
    }

    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    public function getIp()
    {
        return $this->ip;
    }
}
```

### User Provider

```
class CompanyUserProvider implements UserProviderInterface
{
    private $documentManager;

    public function __construct($doctrineMongoDB)
    {
        $this->doctrineMongoDB = $doctrineMongoDB;
    }

    public function loadUserByUsername($username)
    {
        // Not used but needed by the interface
    }

    public function loadUserByUsernamePassword($username, $password, $ip)
    {
        // Does the magic, retrieve user datas from DB.

        return $user;
    }

    public function refreshUser(UserInterface $user)
    {
        // Does nearly the same thing that the above method
        return $refreshedUser;
    }

    public function supportsClass($class)
    {
        return $class === 'Company\UserBundle\Document\User';
    }
}
```

### service.yml

```
parameters: 
    security.authentication.handler.class: Company\UserBundle\Security\Authentication\Handler\CompnayAuthenticationHandler
    company_user_provider.class: Company\UserBundle\Security\User\CompanyUserProvider

services:
    security.authentication.handler:
        class: %security.authentication.handler.class%
        public: false
        arguments: [@router, @security.http_utils]

    company.security.authentication.provider:
        class: Company\UserBundle\Security\Authentication\Provider\CompanyProvider
        arguments: [@company_user_provider]

    company.security.authentication.listener:
        class: Company\UserBundle\Security\Firewall\CompanyListener
        arguments: [@security.context, @security.authentication.manager, @security.authentication.session_strategy, @security.http_utils, "company", @security.authentication.handler, @security.authentication.handler, {}, @logger, @event_dispatcher, @user.service.captcha]

    company_user_provider:
        class: %company_user_provider.class%
        arguments: [@doctrine_mongodb]

    user.service.captcha:
        class: Company\UserBundle\Services\CaptchaService
        arguments: [@form.factory]
```

### security.yml

```
jms_security_extra:
    secure_all_services: false
    expressions: true

security:
    encoders:
        Company\UserBundle\Document\User: plaintext

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_VIP_USER:    ROLE_USER
        ROLE_ADMIN:       [ROLE_USER, ROLE_VIP_USER]

    providers:
        webservice:
            id: company_user_provider

    firewalls:  
        company_secured:
            pattern: ^/
            company: true
            anonymous: true
            form_login:
                login_path: login
                check_path: login_check
                post_only: true
                use_referer: false
                success_handler: security.authentication.handler
                failure_handler: security.authentication.handler
            logout: 
                path: /logout
                target: login

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/admin, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

## Update

Here are some `var_dumps` to explain my problem :

#### UserProvider

`var_dump($user);`

```
object(Company\UserBundle\Document\User)[142]
  protected 'username' => string 'Supacoco' (length=13)
  protected 'roles' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'ROLE_ADMIN' (length=10)
```

#### AuthenticationProvider

`var_dump($authenticatedToken->getUser());`

```
object(Company\UserBundle\Document\User)[142]
  protected 'username' => string 'Supacoco' (length=13)
  protected 'roles' => 
    array (size=1)
      0 => string 'ROLE_ADMIN' (length=10)
```

#### Listener

`var_dump($authToken->getUser());`

```
object(Company\UserBundle\Document\User)[142]
  protected 'username' => string 'Supacoco' (length=13)
  protected 'roles' => 
    array (size=0)
      empty
```

Comment: What roles are you adding?  Not sure if this could be the issue but if i recall correctly, they need to be also prefixed with ROLE_ ie ROLE_XYZ.

Comment: In fact I'm not trying to add a ROLE. In the database, users have their roles (prefixed by ROLE_). But when the Listener tries to authenticate the user, it seems that user's roles disappear at the moment that the token is authenticated. (I hope I've been clear enough)

Comment: show your security.yml please and url where you send login and password

Comment: I added `security.yml`. The form is sent to the default route : /login_check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a lot, I discovered that the "AuthenticationProviderManager", after authenticating the token, calls by default the user's method "EraseCredentials".

The code below explains why my user loses his/her roles after logging in.

```
public function eraseCredentials()
{
    $this->roles = array();
}
```